# INSERT values to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

If i have my SQL create statement as follows;

```
CREATE TABLE TABLENAME12
(
  TAB_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NAME_FIRST NVARCHAR(200),
  TYPE NVARCHAR(200),
  PRIMARY KEY( TAB_ID )
);
```

and if i want to Insert values to it, should i enter `TAB_ID` too ? Since it's auto increment.

When i `INSERT INTO SWM_SALES_FEEDBACK VALUES (1,'Jerry','ty');` It gets inserted if i don't specify the primary key `INSERT INTO SWM_SALES_FEEDBACK VALUES ('Jerry','ty');` i get the following error :

```
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

1.) What is the point of having AUTO_INCREMENT if it doesn't get auto incremented.
2.) If i have a field called:

```
BIRTH_TIME DATE,
```

How should i INSERT value to this field since it's  `DATE` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Point 1`

If you don't want to store all fields in DB then you have to specify those column names before `VALUES` clause as shown below.

```
INSERT INTO myTable (field2,field3) VALUES ('field2','field3')
```

In your case, statement should be

```
INSERT INTO SWM_SALES_FEEDBACK (name_first, type) VALUES ('Jerry','ty')
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

### `Point 2`

If you have field as DATETIME, TIMESTAMP as datatype, you can enter date as

```
INSERT INTO myTable (myDate) VALUES ('2012-12-28 12:12:12')
```

Format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

If you want to store the current time of the system in DB, you could use `NOW()` as shown below.

```
INSERT INTO myTable (myDate) VALUES (NOW())
```

Answer (score 6):

1) You have to respect an order of columns in your table. You can do either:

```
INSERT INTO SWM_SALES_FEEDBACK VALUES (null, 'Jerry','ty');
```

or

```
INSERT INTO SWM_SALES_FEEDBACK (NAME_FIRST, TYPE) VALUES ('Jerry','ty');
```

2) You can use '2012-07-24' format for date column.

Answer (score 3):

With an auto increment, you need to specify your columns

```
INSERT INTO tablename12 ('name_first','type') values ('Jerry','ty')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't inserting into every column, you need to tell the query which columns you want to insert into. try `INSERT INTO SWM_SALES_FEEDBACK (NAME_FIRST,TYPE) VALUES ('Jerry','ty');`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if mysql has a to_date() function in the new releases:

But, you can use this : Just enclose the date time field in single quotes. You can specify the date time formats

```
  INSERT INTO table_name (birth_date) VALUES ('2008-07-04')
```

For other date format questions refer [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

For your auto increment, specify the columns

```
INSERT INTO SWM_SALES_FEEDBACK (NAME_FIRST,TYPE) VALUES ('Jerry','ty');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
INSERT INTO SWM_SALES_FEEDBACK (NAME_FIRST,TYPE) VALUES ('Jerry','ty');
```